# FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)

Tags: ionic-framework

I am freaking out right now - as I am in the midst of debugging this idiot bug.

Framework: Ionic + Angular

Im' not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I already call the initializeApp in my app.module.ts as seen here :

[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Cqc.png)

And also I had it running yesterday night already.  but now it just seems to NOT WORKING OMG.

[bugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTKP8.png)

Anyone faced this problem before?